# Add Instagram to UIActivityViewController

Tags: swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm trying to share an image using standard `UIActivityViewController`, it's fine to share on **Facebook**, **Twitter** and **Save Image** using this code:

```
let firstActivityItem = "foo text"
let secondActivityItem : UIImage = image!

let activityViewController : UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
    activityItems: [firstActivityItem, secondActivityItem], applicationActivities: nil)

activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [
    UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
    UIActivityTypePrint,
    UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
    UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
    UIActivityTypePostToVimeo,
    UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo
]

self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I need one more thing, **Instagram**:

```
If UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(instagramURL!) {
            // Success
            var img = image!

            var savePath: String = NSHomeDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("Documents/Test.igo")
            UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1).writeToFile(savePath, atomically: true)
            var imgURL = NSURL(string: NSString(format: "file://%@", savePath) as! String)
            docController = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL: imgURL!) // 1
            docController.UTI = "com.instagram.exclusivegram" // 2
            docController.delegate = self
            docController.annotation = ["InstagramCaption":"testsss"] // 3
            docController.presentOpenInMenuFromRect(self.view.frame, inView: self.view, animated: true) // 4
        } else {
            // Error
        }
```

Both these codes work fine separately, how can I add **Instagram** to the `UIActivityViewController`? Is it possible at all?

Comment: Did you get any solution to add Instagram in UIActivityViewController?

Comment: @EktaPadaliya yes, check the marked answer

Comment: But that is "UIDocumentInteractionController". I want with "UIActivityController"

Comment: @EktaPadaliya join here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163403/swift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be very easier to add other social shares to the code you wrote for Instagram. The ".igo" extension is exclusive for Instagram so other apps will not support it. Just change this extension from ".igo" to ".ig" and other apps will read it:

```
var savePath: String = NSHomeDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("Documents/Test.ig")
```

But Instagram also have an exclusive UTI to avoiding other apps to appear in the same Document Interaction View. So you will also need to change it from "exclusivegram" to "photo":

```
docController.UTI = "com.instagram.photo"
```

I have an app with a similar functionality and this is my original code:

```
@IBAction func shareOnIntagram(sender: UIButton) {

        let finalImage: UIImage = UIImage.imageWithView(photoView)
        let instagramURL = NSURL(string: "instagram://app")
        if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(instagramURL!)) {

            let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(finalImage, 1)
            let captionString = "caption"
            let writePath = (NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("instagram.ig")
            if imageData?.writeToFile(writePath, atomically: true) == false {

                return

            } else {

                let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: writePath)
                self.documentController = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL: fileURL)
                self.documentController.delegate = self
                self.documentController.UTI = "com.instagram.photo"
                self.documentController.annotation = NSDictionary(object: captionString, forKey: "InstagramCaption")
                self.documentController.presentOpenInMenuFromRect(self.view.frame, inView: self.view, animated: true)
            }

        } else {
            print(" Instagram is not installed ")
        }
    }
```

To make this code work, don't forget to add `UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate` in the UIViewController class.

Comment: just put file:// before the writePath..It worked for me after putting  writePath = "file://" + writePath

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's not possible, because of `.igo` extension which is needed by Instagram.