# How to share a Image on Instagram correctly?

Tags: ios, swift, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-story

How can I share a UIImage with the Instagram App?

I know, this topic has been discussed many times. But due to the evolution of SWIFT, I hope to find a better solution. I found two different ways to do it, Both work on my device:

1.) First approach: UIApplication.shared.open()

```
func backgroundImage(_ backgroundImage: Data, attributionURL: String) {
    // Verify app can open custom URL scheme, open if able
    guard let urlScheme = URL(string: "instagram-stories://share"),
        UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(urlScheme) else {
            // Handle older app versions or app not installed case
            return
    }

    let pasteboardItems = [["com.instagram.sharedSticker.backgroundImage": backgroundImage,
                            "com.instagram.sharedSticker.contentURL": attributionURL]]
    let pasteboardOptions: [UIPasteboard.OptionsKey: Any] = [.expirationDate: Date().addingTimeInterval(60 * 5)]

    UIPasteboard.general.setItems(pasteboardItems, options: pasteboardOptions)

    UIApplication.shared.open(urlScheme)
}
```

**This opens my image directly** in the Instagram App. So far so good, but in this way, it's only possible to share in **Instagram STORIES**.

2.) Second approach: UIDocumentInteractionController()

```
private let kInstagramURL = "instagram://"
private let kUTI = "com.instagram.exclusivegram"
private let kfileNameExtension = "instagram.igo"
```

[...]

```
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(instagramURL! as URL) {

        let jpgPath = (NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString).appendingPathComponent(kfileNameExtension)

        do {
            try UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageInstagram, 0.75)?.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: jpgPath), options: .atomic)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        let rect = CGRect.zero
        let fileURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: jpgPath)

        documentInteractionController.url = fileURL
        documentInteractionController.delegate = self
        documentInteractionController.uti = kUTI

        // adding caption for the image
        documentInteractionController.annotation = ["InstagramCaption": instagramCaption]
        documentInteractionController.presentOpenInMenu(from: rect, in: view, animated: true)
        //documentInteractionController.presentOptionsMenu(from: rect, in: view, animated: true)
}
```

This opens the UIDocumentInteractionController Popup, where the user can select the App with which he wants to share. Unfortunately many Apps can handle "instagram.igo":
[Screenshot of Popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WUec.png)

**My problem now:**

- I want to let the user select, if he wants to share in Feed or Stories, therefore solution No.1 is no option (only stories possible)
- The UIInteractionController opens the silly popup with too many Apps.

**My question now:**
There is a solution to open the app directly, without popup! But is it also possible, to reach the Instagram-Selection-Screen directly without popup?
[Instagram Selection Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Obly0.png)

There is no help in the [Insta Developer Hooks](https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/)

Comment: Did you try to use a `UIActivityViewController`?

activity controller has a `excludedActivityTypes` that can limit the share options

Comment: possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30939686/add-instagram-to-uiactivityviewcontroller

Comment: Yes, I already tried. But it's the same result like the InteractionController. I think it's not feasible to exclude ALL the possible Apps a user can have...

Is there a possibility in the ActivityController, to allow only ONE specific App?

Comment: Yeah, there is. It's initializer have a parameter `applicationActivities` that are an array of the `UIActivity` that you want to share, but you will need to create a custom one for the instagram using it application bundle because it does not have a default for it.

Comment: Answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58262862/4934534